# How to make bundles communicate in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, structure, bundle

I am making an administration menu bundle. I want other bundles to be able to add menu items to the bundle, but I also want the menu items to be deleted when a bundle is removed. What would be the best way to do this?

I could create a 'regenerate admin menu' action that scans all bundles for a certain YML and then store that in cache or database.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [tags](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html) to find services from other bundles (or even the same) and use them to build menu from them in [compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html).

In this example I will assume you have your menu defined as a service (I will use service id `acme_menu.menu`).

```
// src/Acme/MenuBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/BuildMenuCompilerPass.php
namespace Acme\MenuBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class BuildMenuCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->hasDefinition('acme_menu.menu')) {
            return;
        }

        $definition = $container->getDefinition('acme_menu.menu');

        $taggedServices = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('acme_menu.item');
        foreach ($taggedServices as $id => $attributes) {
            $definition->addMethodCall(
                'addMenuItem',
                array(new Reference($id))
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Register it with your menu bundle:

```
// src/Acme/MenuBundle/AcmeMenuBundle.php
namespace Acme\MenuBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

use Acme\MenuBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\BuildMenuCompilerPass;

class AcmeMenuBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new BuildMenuCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

And every service tagged as `acme_menu.item` will be added to the menu - them method `addMenuItem` will be called on the menu on it's creation with the tagged service as a parameter. So simply define:

```
# services.yml
services:
    acme_demo.menu.item1:
        # ...
        tags:
            - { name: acme_menu.item }
    acme_demo.menu.item2:
        # ...
        tags:
            - { name: acme_menu.item }
```